# PowerApps - The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerapps

I am working on PowerApp, I got the below error when i added few columns in the sharepoint list.

**The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold**

[image]

I have read some article those says that sharepoint online 2013 supports only 12 lookup columns [Here the link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/12/02/sharepoint-20102013-list-view-lookup-threshold-uncovered/).

My List contains almost 15 People picker fields which causes this issue.
How should I removed this error. Any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

You can consider reworking this solution. Could you lower the number of people pickers - maybe make some of them multi people pickers. You could also split the list into two lists of data.

Comment: i am also fighting this issue.  :(  i need all the fields.